# FTP upload file to distant server with CURL and PHP uploads a blank file

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to upload a file to a distant server, but looks like the source file does nothing. All i get is a blank file on the server.
My code is this:

```
<?php

    $c = curl_init();
    $file = "\PATHTOFILE\file.txt";
    $fp = fopen($file, "r");

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "SERVERPATH/file.txt");
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "USER:PASSWORD");
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file));

    curl_exec($c);
      echo "Success";
    curl_close($c);
    fclose($fp); 

?>
```

Comment: try `echo curl_errno($ch);` to see if there is any error

Comment: Tried it and got 0, now what does it means?

Comment: what is the format of SERVERPATH? i.e. just change the host name but leave all the other stuff, punctuation, etc.

Comment: This is the host path:ftp.ans.projects.jce.ac.il/public_ftp/incoming/file.txt
I think its correct because when i open the file management system i can see a file, but it's a blank one

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After 2 days of banging my head against the keyboard.. finally i did it..
Here is how:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
 if (!empty($_FILES['upload']['name'])) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $localfile = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
    $fp = fopen($localfile, 'r');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://domain.com/'.$_FILES['upload']['name']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));
    curl_exec ($ch);
    $error_no = curl_errno($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
        if ($error_no == 0) {
            $error = 'File uploaded succesfully.';
        } else {
            $error = 'File upload error.';
        }
 } else {
        $error = 'Please select a file.';
 }
}
  echo $error;  
?>
```

Here is the [source](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/tutorial-ftp-upload-via-curl/), from where i found the solution

Comment: Hi, i am giving +1, because CURLOPT_UPLOAD = 1 without this curlopt it really uploads empty file on the server, i was trying to upload to nextcloud