# PHP's cURL gives error 425 on FTP uploads

Tags: php, curl

Trying to upload a file over FTP using cURL but it isn't working as expected.

Server:

- Apache 2.2.25
- PHP 5.3.27

The following works:

```
    $url = 'ftp.someserver.com';
    $file = '/path/to/file.xml';
    $filename = basename($file);

    $conn_id = ftp_connect($url);

    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $auth['user'], $auth['pass']);

    if (ftp_put($conn_id, "/remotedir/$filename", $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
        $success = true;
    } else {
        $success = false;
    }

    ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Try this with cURL and the connection times out with FTP error 425 and a blank file is left on the  remote server:

```
    $url = 'FTP://ftp.someserver.com/remotedir/';
    $file = '/path/to/file.xml';
    $filename = basename($file);
    $fp = fopen($file, 'r');

    $fstat = fstat($fp);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . $filename);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, rawurlencode($auth['user']) . ':' . rawurlencode($auth['pass']));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $fstat['size']);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    fclose($fp);
```

I've also tried connecting with options `CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPRT` and `CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPSV` enabled but same result.

What am I missing here to make this work with cURL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906555/ftp-upload-file-to-distant-server-with-curl-and-php-uploads-a-blank-file

Comment: @joschua011 Saw that post already. Our code is functionally the same if you look at it. I'm still getting the error though.