# Uploading via CURL - how can I change the destination file name?

Tags: php, curl

I am uploading a CSV file daily to another FTP Server:

```
$post["File1"] = new CurlFile($local_path);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $upload_config->ChunkUri);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

$upload_response = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Assuming my $local_path variable is:

"../downloads/reports/file/2015-07-30.csv"

I want the file to upload to server with the file name: 2015-07-30.csv

But more often than not it comes out as:

downloadsreportsfile2015-07-30.csv - ridiculous!!!!

The weird thing is, SOMETIMES the file uploads with the original file name, but most of the time the file is uploaded with the file name a combination of the whole folder path.

I cannot figure out why it would do both randomly. The file name is just the days date and the folder path is consistent.

Is there an option to explicitly set the the file name?

Comment: Look at [the class constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php)

Comment: If you are using FTP, try uploading the file directly, i.e. specify the name in the CURLOPT_URL instead of using CURLOPT_POST. See an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9924481/192331

Comment: I got it working using this: $post["File1"] = new CurlFile($local_path, "text/csv", $actual_filename); - but obviously I've hard coded the middle parameter. Can I leave it blank or would it be required to set the file name after it?

Comment: You could use [finfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) to get the mime type.

Comment: Legend @Janci thank you. Hadn't seen that one before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get value for mime file using this code

```
<?php
    function getmimefile($file){
        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $ftype = finfo_file($finfo,$file);
        finfo_close($finfo);
        return $ftype;
    }
```

so you can handle mimefile like this

```
$post["File1"] = new CurlFile($local_path, getmimefile($local_path), $actual_filename);
```