# Upload the file to the FTP server over HTTPS using curl in php

Tags: php, curl, file-upload, https, ftp

I am trying to upload the data [can be text or zip] to the ftp site.
As we have proxy in place in the environment so, I decided to upload the data using curl. Before I go head to set proxy server setting, I was testing the script on the environment without proxy.

I followed :-
[FTP upload file to distant server with CURL and PHP uploads a blank file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906555/ftp-upload-file-to-distant-server-with-curl-and-php-uploads-a-blank-file)

However, I couldn't able to upload a file.

link where, I would like to upload is this format:-
https://fp.emc.com/.....

Do any one know, how to upload a file to ftp server over https using curl function of PHP?

```
<?php
$sendTo = 'https://ftp.emc.com/....?domain=XX&user=XXX&password=XXX'; 
$localfile ="23.txt";
$fp = fopen($localfile, 'r');
// Create CURL Connection 
$ch = curl_init(); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "usr:passwd"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sendTo); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));
echo $ch;
$m=curl_exec ($ch);
echo "m $m<br>";
    $error_no = curl_errno($ch);
    echo "error_no $error_no<br>";
    curl_close ($ch);
        if ($error_no == 0) {
            $error = 'File uploaded succesfully.';
        } else {
            $error = 'File upload error.';
        }
echo $error;
?>
```

Comment: try using `CURL POST` instead of `GET`. Just add this o your curl options: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`

Comment: Yes, I added 
$fields="domain=xXX&username=XX&password=XX";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);


Still not working, stackOver flow is full of ftp:\\ftp.example.com
However, I am working with https:\\ftp.example.com

Comment: You cannot upload with an HTTP(S) to an FTP server. It's not an FTP server, if it uses the HTTP(S) for upload. Please make it clear, what you ask for.

Comment: I can uplad the file using ftp_put, however I have to upload the script to the enironment where we cannot access external work utill we use the proxy server, Hence ftp_put option I had to eliminate.
With curl as we can mention the proxy details.

ftp.emc.com opens in browser? - yes  and can upload the file.

In the browser : link look like this https:\\ftp.emc.com\....?domain=XX&user=XX&password=XXX

When I am trying to upload a file on the above mention ftp link then I experence issue.

Comment: Above code, I am using to upload to https://ftp.emc.com, I tried both get and post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$fp = fopen($filepath, 'r');

$ftp_url = "ftp://user:password@ftpserver:21/" . $filename;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ftp_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($filepath));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_server_ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_server_port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxy_login);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

It works for me.

Comment: I used same code which didn't work but, the only parameter which I never introduced CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD because when we apply proxy on the WEB Browser at that moment we didn't specify any proxy user password. Could you help me explanation of CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD option. So that I could introduce in my problematic script.

Comment: Strange this curl_errno is also 0, but when access FTP link then it is not uploaded

Comment: The CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD contain the **$proxy_user.":".$proxy_pass** string.