# uploading ftp file in php

Tags: php, curl, ftp

does anyone here know how to upload file to shutterstock ftp using php code?

```
     $upURL = "ftp.shutterstock.com/";
    echo $upURL;
    //die();

    $fp = fopen($localfile, "r");
  //  echo $fp;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://".$upURL.$remotefile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.":".$pass);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, (int)$img->image_size);
    curl_exec ($ch);
    $error_no = curl_errno($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code? is it crashing? what is the expected result and what is the actual result?

Comment: hi, well, expected result is to return the name of the image uploaded. what i get is an error message

Comment: Hi HomerSenpai. could you please add the error message and explain what happens. Also have a look at [FTP upload file to distant server with CURL and PHP uploads a blank file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9924481/5841606)

Comment: thank's a lot @Uwe for the link.  i get "EOSR6760-2.jpgftp.shutterstock.com/File upload error."